# Won't & Don't Usage

Tags: word-choice, grammar

What is the difference between the phrase "They won't let me go." and "They don't let me go."
Is the latter correct?

Answer (score 0):

It's a difference of *when* the action takes place:

> They don't let me go.

They do not let me go, at this moment, as we speak.

> They won't let me go.

They *will* not let me go. Not at this moment, but also not in the future.

Another example would be:

> I don't do drugs.

At this moment, and in general, I do not use drugs.

> I won't do drugs.

I will not use drugs in the future. Or possibly, I will not use drugs at a specific event in the future.

In practice, the two versions overlap quite a bit in meaning, and often one can be substituted for the other, even though there is a subtle difference in meaning.